# "Espresso Testing Framework does not support Compose projects" when recording Firebase Test Lab Robot Script

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

Android Studio when I create *Firebase Test Lab* -> Record Robot Script so errors **is Espresso Testing Framework does not support Compose projects.**

do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot record a Robo script for a Compose project in Android Studio, because of the limitations of the underlying framework. However, you can create a Robo script manually following the [Robo scripts reference guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-scripts-reference) and then run this Robo script in Firebase Test Lab.

Comment: any alternate solution to write auto script json code for Firebase test lab??

Comment: As of now, there is no publicly available Robo script Recorder besides the one in Android Studio, which does not work for Compose projects. However, it should not be hard to write a Robo script manually following the reference guide.